# How to define a list of output when using list and for_each in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to deploy BigQuery scheduled query using terraform but I do not know how I can use `list` and `for_each` syntax.

I have this template file.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mydataset.mytable_${suffix}
```

Then generate a list of query using template_file module. `var.suffix_list` here is a list of string.

```yaml
data "template_file" "query" {
  for_each = var.suffix_list # list(string)
  template = "file/path/to/template/file"
  vars = {
    suffix    = each.value
  }
}
```

From this module I want to generate a list of query.

```yaml
output "query" {
  value = # a list of rendered query
}
```

This output will be an input of `google_bigquery_data_transfer_config` resource.

```
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {
  for_each                 = # a list of rendered query
  data_refresh_window_days = var.data_refresh_window_days
  data_source_id           = "scheduled_query"
  display_name             = var.display_name
  disabled                 = var.disabled
  destination_dataset_id   = var.destination_dataset_id
  location                 = var.query_location
  project                  = var.gcp_project
  schedule                 = var.query_schedule
  params = {
    destination_table_name_template = var.destination_table_name_template
    query                           = each.value
  }
}
```

How can I output definition and an input for `google_bigquery_data_transfer_config`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things are necessary to make this work.

Your argument to `for_each` should be a set, so you'll need to use

```
  for_each = toset(var.suffix_list)
```

In your template itself the variable is named `suffix`, however, you're passing the variable `schema`. These ought to match.

The `template` argument actually needs to be the text of the template. So you'll need to read the file in using the `file` function, e.g.

```
  template = file("path/to/template/file")
```

Then, finally, to write your actual output, you can use a list comprehension

```
output "query" {
  value = [for query in data.template_file.query : query.rendered]
}
```

Comment: Would you also advise me how I can use the output "query" in the resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config"?